# Ziggeo: Submitted event fired multiple times

Tags: javascript

We are using ZIGGEO to record video interviews in our new platform. I have noticed that sometimes it seems that the submitted event is fired more than once when the user submit the video. It doesn't happen all the time. Is it something that we can control?

```
 ziggeo.ZiggeoApi.Events.on("submitted", (data: any) => {
                this.addAnswer(data);
            });
```

The addAnswer method is called multiple times, sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw that you send us a message to support as well Jordi, as mentioned there happy to help you with this here or there :)

- For those that do not know I work at Ziggeo :)

In regards to the submitted event it would usually be called as:

```
ZiggeoApi.Events.on("submitted", function ( data ) {
    //Your code goes here
});
```

I am not sure if the way you are using it currently could cause any issues, however what I presume to be happening is that there might be 2 embeddings on the page.

The reason why I say that is because v1's *submitted* event will fire each time some (any) Ziggeo embedding on your page raises the same.

If you want to make sure that events fire in more private manner, I would actually suggest using v2.

I consider v2 much better than v1 in a lot of different aspects, while both are great on its own (good to point out that these are 2 different systems if you will, v2 is not built on top of v1).

While v2 does not have `submitted` event it has a better one called `verified` which fires once the video is uploaded and before processing, requiring less time to tell you if the video would for some reason fail to be processed or not - you can read more about that on [our forum](https://support.ziggeo.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/217975707-Wondering-where-submitted-event-is-when-using-v2-Then-check-this-out)

This would make it fire for specific video only, and could not be affected by multiple embeddings so I would suggest trying that one out.

You can see how to set it up:

1. [The embedding
   codes](https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/javascript/browser-integration/embed-methods)
2. [Available
   parameters](https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/javascript/browser-integration/parameters)
3. [Events](https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/javascript/browser-interaction/events)

   - on all of those pages you can change the version (v1 / v2) and on some even the revision to show you only relevant details for revision you are using.

PS: Might be good to see if this is specific to any browser maybe as well, causing the event to be called again for some reason.